# Lp spaces real anlysis

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $s\le t$ then

$a)$ ${ L }^{ t }\left( \left[ 0,1 \right]  \right) \subseteq { L }^{ s }\left( \left[ 0,1 \right]  \right) $

$b)$ The identity function is continuous (between metric spaces)

$c)$ Gives an example of a function $f\in { L }^{ 1 }\left( \left[ 0,1 \right]  \right) \diagdown { L }^{ 2 }\left( \left[ 0,1 \right]  \right) $

$d)$ Is there a continuous function $g\in { L }^{ 1 }\left( \left[ 0,1 \right]  \right) \diagdown { L }^{ 2 }\left( \left[ 0,1 \right]  \right) $?

Comment: a) Hölder inequality b) is an implication of a)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: In a) you can assume $s<t$, then there is a $r$ such that $s+r=t$

Comment: In $(d)$, do you mean a continuous function on $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) For $t=\infty$

$$\|f\|_s^s=\int_{[0,1]}|f|^sdm \le \|f\|_{\infty}$$

For $t \lt \infty$, applying Holder's inequlaity to the pairs $\frac{t}{s}$ and $\frac{t}{t-s}$ we have $$\|f\|_s^s=\int_{[0,1]}|f|^s 1dm \le \|f\|_t^s \lt \infty$$

(b)Follows from (a)